# An error while importing an image as a variable into Matlab

Tags: matlab, input, tiff

I wanted to import a tif image into Matlab workspace as a variable using File/import data tool. But I got the following error "Warning: The datatype for tag SamplesPerPixel should be TIFF_SHORT instead of TIFF_LONG. This may cause data corruption". The image type is float single, 32 bit. and size is really big (4144,12619,7). Can matlab read and display such an image. What does this error mean? and how can I correct it?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Read the [TIFF specification](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf).

From the warning message it appears there's some problem with the format chosen. When reading a TIFF file, each IFD has many entries, one of them being SamplesPerPixel (see page 24 of the specification). This should be of type SHORT (see page 15 for the list of types and what they are). However, apparently, you have type LONG there. That seems to be causing problem. Either matlab is identifying it incorrectly, or the software you used to save the image is not following the TIFF specification.